# Java 2 Platform, Enterprise Edition 1.3 Specification

Tags: jakarta-ee, specifications

Does anyone know where can I find it?

[Link in Oracle.com](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/index-jsp-140710.html#platformspec) won't open.
And [link in jcp.org](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.3/index.jsp) also ain't working. 
Google didn't help much either.

I did find specifications for 1.2 and 1.4 but can't find for 1.3.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you're after? https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/review/jsr058/J2EE_Platform_Spec.pdf

It's not the final version but should come close.

Comment: Well, was looking for final release, but this is atleast something. I need specifications for all Java EE versions for my bachelor thesis. I was quite sure that Oracle does provide them all, but I was wrong. All links for Java2EE specifications are broken.

Comment: @Belamors that's a shame. Maybe you can contact Oracle about this.